# Search by foreign key

Tags: php, sql

I’m working on an application that allows users to search for music, artists, albums and mixtapes.
The DB has these four tables: Music, Artists, Mixtapes, Albums.
The 3 tables; mixtapes, music and albums are related to the artist using foreign keys in a column called artist_id.
It is quite easy to get search results from each of the three tables by using a query such as this:

```
$music = "SELECT * FROM music WHERE song_title LIKE '%$search_term%'";
```

However, I’m finding it a bit daunting to get results for albums, mixtapes and music where artist_name = search term since the artist’s reference is not made by name but rather by artist_id
How can I return results for music, albums and mixtapes for a user supplied search term (ie. artist)?

Comment: You're injecting variables into your SQL query and hence making your script very insecure. What if I did this (and you have enabled multi queries)? `search_term='; DROP TABLE music; --`

Comment: @h2ooooooo from the sample, it's not obvious (how do we know - may be OP doing escaping before query). But to the matter - please, provide sample data

Comment: @AlmaDo You're completely correct, but I'd rather make sure to tell someone that they're doing something insecure and be wrong than not telling them and risking that they upload code like this. For some reason many newcommers to PHP figure it's a great idea to simply inject variables.

Comment: Make a join between tables. Then search in each of them with "like" clause with using "OR".

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm sanitizing the $search_term before doing the query. I'll go ahead and perform the suggested JOIN between tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an `inner join`

```
"SELECT * FROM music INNER JOIN artist ON music.artist_id = artist.id WHERE artist.name LIKE '%$search_term%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join between the tables, something like this:

```
select * from music m
inner join artists a on (m.artist_id = a.artist_id)
where a.artist name like ....
```